# MongoDB query error occurs during: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.ExpressionVisitor not found by org.eclipse.persistence.core

Tags: mongodb, eclipselink, nosql

I'm trying execute simple queries with EclipseLink on MongoDB. I took advantage of this [example](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/java_ee_6_and_nosql).

My GlassFish version 3.1.2 By following this [example](https://blogs.oracle.com/GlassFishPersistence/entry/updating_eclipselink_bundles_in_glassfish), I did an update of EclipseLink.

When I execute the following query, I get an error.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("Select o from Order");
```

or

```
Query query = em.createQuery("Select o from Order o where o.totalCost > 1000");
```

and so on.

```
WARNING: #{myBean.testPersist}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/parser/ExpressionVisitor
javax.faces.FacesException: #{myBean.testPersist}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/parser/ExpressionVisitor
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/parser/ExpressionVisitor
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/parser/ExpressionVisitor
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getClassForName(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.buildDefaultQueryBuilder(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.getQueryBuilder(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1510)
    at com.kodcu.bean.MyBean.sorgu(MyBean.java:169)
    at com.kodcu.bean.MyBean.testPersist(MyBean.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.ExpressionVisitor not found by org.eclipse.persistence.core [254]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 54 more
```

I am not receiving an error during the insertion process.

Comment: Seem like some jar is missing. Have you followed the step 3 properly?

Comment: Hi Miguel. As I said before I tried to implement following the example. For example, I changed it filename: org.eclipse.persistence.core_2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345.jar to org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you include the EclipseLink antlr, hermes and nosql osgi bundle jars in Glassfish's classpath.